# Perform Row Functions in a View

Tags: views

Trying to get a calculation at the end of an [Aggregated Table](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator) or even [Pivot Table](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_pivot) in [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views), but as it seems to be a bit of a two step process, I can't figure it out for the life of me...

I have the following table of user skills, pulled together using aggregation (for a number of reasons the way the data has to be gathered). I can also use a pivot to the same result.

[image]

I want to then be able to evaluate overall skill of each user by counting the Lows, Mediums and Highs for each user, multiplying them by 1, 2 and 3 respectively, and then add them together to a Total Skill value, per below:

[image]

Any ideas on how to do this, or an appropriate module that would give me this result?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `THEME_preprocess_views_view_fields(&$var)` function? In this function you may get every field of the view, and do any processing you want just before loading the view. just install [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module, and use `kpr` to see what variables are available.

Comment: Thanks @Drupalist - I'll give this a go - do you know any resources that give a good overview using this function?

Comment: it is not complicated. When the page is loaded every view calls this function before loading and all of the variables are stored in `$var` variable. for example the statement `$view = $var['view']` returns the view or `$view->type` returns its type. You only check for the view type then by `kpr` see the available variables. in this link, there is a tutorial of theming views slideshow using this function. http://www.joetower.com/2011/11/drupal-7-theming-views-slideshow/